# Changing elements of Ionic ion-item in CSS

Tags: ionic4, ion-item

I would like to change the behavior of the flex property of ion-item without using the slot because when I test on my windows 10 application the slot doesn't work, I searched on a forum and it says to use ion-item::part(native) but this solution doesn't work or maybe I'm using it wrong, do you have an idea how to do it?

My demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-szd9ax?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab1%2Ftab1.page.scss

the ion-item::part article: https://ionic.io/blog/customize-your-ionic-framework-app-with-css-shadow-parts